# OpenCL Device Query

Tags: opencl

I am new to OpenCL and trying to run the sample code from nvidia 'OpenCL device query' available here (https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl) on ubuntu 12.04

I get a lots of undefined reference for:
std::basic_string
shrLogEx
shrLog
shrSetLogFileName

I guess i have made some mistakes in including the proper header files but cannot locate the problem. Could anyone please let me know how to run the sample code?

Following is the error message:

```
oclDeviceQuery.o: In function `main':  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x45): undefined reference to `shrSetLogFileName'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x61): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x77): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x92): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0xb0): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `oclGetPlatformID'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x15d): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x176): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x191): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x215): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x230): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x244): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x258): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x26c): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x27b): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x2ca): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x2e5): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x30b): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x32e): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x366): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x39f): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x43b): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x465): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x4b4): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x4c3): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x4e4): undefined reference to `oclPrintDevInfo'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x4f8): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x511): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x548): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x563): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::operator+=(char const*)'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x572): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::c_str() const'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x589): undefined reference to `shrLogEx'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x598): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x5d2): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x5fa): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x617): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'  
oclDeviceQuery.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x658): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::Init()'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text+0x65d): undefined reference to `std::ios_base::Init::~Init()'  
oclDeviceQuery.o: In function `__oclCheckErrorEX(int, int, void (*)(int), char const*, int)':  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text._Z17__oclCheckErrorEXiiPFviEPKci[__oclCheckErrorEX(int, int, void (*)(int), char const*, int)]+0x3b): undefined reference to `oclErrorString'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text._Z17__oclCheckErrorEXiiPFviEPKci[__oclCheckErrorEX(int, int, void (*)(int), char const*, int)]+0x5c): undefined reference to `shrLog'  
oclDeviceQuery.cpp:(.text._Z17__oclCheckErrorEXiiPFviEPKci[__oclCheckErrorEX(int, int, void (*)(int), char const*, int)]+0x89): undefined reference to `shrLogEx'  
oclDeviceQuery.o:(.eh_frame+0xe7): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is actually not your fault, but in fact NVIDIA's: essentially they've dropped their opencl support. Hardly surprising since they want you to use CUDA. They took the opencl samples out of the main cuda SDK and instead uploaded them one by one. Now they've got missing dependencies and none of them work.

To workaround, download the old version of the SDK: pick appropriate version from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-42-archive

For linux: once downloaded, run it from a terminal using the usual `./gpucomputing*.run` . During the installation procedure, I suggest when prompted you choose to put the sdk in your home folder `/home/usrname/gpusdk`, or else it will extract to root. Next I got a message about could not locate CUDA, so I just left that blank.

In a terminal, navigate to `/home/usrname/gpusdk/OpenCL` and type `make`. It will build the required libraries this time, sort your linking for you, and should compile all the samples fine (at least it did for me)